# Empty Post in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to add the helper _form of my Comment model inside Advertisement view. I call the helper `<%= render 'comments/form', comment: @comment %>`in the route `/advertisement/:id`

So here is my *comments _form* :

```
<%= form_with(model: comment, local: true,  url: "/comments") do |form| %>
  <% if comment &&  comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, class:"form-field" %>
  </div>

  <%= form.hidden_field :advertisment_id, value:params[:id]  %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Envoyer", class:"btn btn-primary", url: 'comments' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I specify the `url: "/comments"` because I'm at `/advertisment/:id` and by default the action is aimed to here.

But when the post reached my comment controller, it can't read the params.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in CommentsController#create
```

The strange part is that I've access to the params :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0+swOqHPEHN2Gwh0TO3iC7VPRz4ROLoBlkaMkOdnjjYxWHoDer7AwrgnQpu+9VHfSY90yMSRsNp8ojvPJxuzmQ==", "content"=>"Test", "advertisment_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Envoyer"}
```

So here is the *comment controller :*

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # [...]

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params.merge(:user_id => @session_user.id))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # [...]

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :advertisment_id)
    end
end
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably because your `@comment` is `nil` so that `form_with` works like the old `form_tag` helper.

By using `form_with`, a field like `<%= form.text_field :content %>`

- If your model is presented, it will generate `<input type="text" name="comment[content]" />`
- If your model is not presented, it will generate `<input type="text" name="content" />`

In the second case, your strong params check will reject the naked params

To be able to solve it, simply assign a valid model to your `render`

```
<%= render 'comments/form', comment: Comment.new %>
```

Comment: Thanks you solution work perfectly. I've one question about the model because for me when I put `<%= render 'comments/form', comment: @comment %>` I give to my `form_with` a model. So why It will generate a `params[:content]` and not a `params[:comment][:content]` as it did when the class is specify ?

Comment: `a model` means an instance object of the targeting model. Only when you give a model, `form_with` assigns the scope to that model name. In your case, since the `@comment` is `nil` so that `form_with` doesn't know the scope, therefore the naked params is generated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with), if you specific `url` option in `form_with` without the `scope` option, the params received will be missing `prefixes` in there name. Therefore

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :advertisment_id)
```

will raise an error since the params does not include `comment`.

You should remove `url` option in your `form_with` or use `url` and `scope` options at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was indeed the lack of `scope` on my `form_with`. I miss this part, so `<%= form_with(model: comment, local: true, scope: :comment,  url: "/comments") do |form| %>` work perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helps, I'd be more than happy to have an upvote.

Comment: I did... but you'll have to wait that I have 15 reputations to see my upvote !